# What is C# equivalent of preg_match_all?

Tags: c#, php, function, match, equivalent

The theme is i opened a file and get all it's data into string and i am matching this string with the regex returning none. But the same regex in PHP is returning values for the same text using preg_match_all. Anyone having a idea?

Comment: Can you post regular expression which works in php but not in c#?

Comment: what is the string? what is the regex? what is the "other" "software" that is returning data but PHP isn't? btw, welome to SO. I hope you have read the FAQ. SO (StackOverflow) will help you a *lot*, just be sure to phrase proper questions. Fyi, I only just joined this site 2 weeks ago, and I realized very soon that SO is very helpful. Pass it on!

Comment: I'd recommend you post a cut of your code, so we can see what is going wrong..

Answer (score 5):

The method in .NET that’s closest to `preg_match_all()` is the static [Regex.Matches(String,String)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b9712a7w.aspx) call, or the equivalent `Matches` method on a compiled regular expression. It returns a `MatchCollection` that you can use to count the matches and to loop over each one.

Can you provide some short, self-contained code to show what’s not working?

Answer (score 0):

There is a Regex.Matches method in C# that you can use.